# Alternatives to smbclient. smbget to talk to samba server

Tags: perl, libcurl, wget, samba, smb

I am looking for alternative clients to communicate with a samba server. Specifically avoiding the use of smbclient, smbget.

Does perl have any modules that can do this ? I looked at libcurl package documentation but seems like it does not support samba implementation.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: So [Filesys::SmbClient](http://search.cpan.org/~alian/Filesys-SmbClient-3.1/SmbClient.pm) does not qualify because using `libsmclient.so`?

Comment: Yup, cannot use the perl module Filesys-SmbClient-3.1

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the use of smbclient? Knowing that should make it possible to give an easier answer to this question.

Comment: Due to security concerns with the smbclient.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux kernel can mount CIFS shares; the implementation of SMB there is completely independent of that in Samba.